# Magento 2.1 - How do I downgrade Algolia Search?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, algolia

I've been using Algolia Search for Magento 2.1 for 2 weeks. Somehow I accidentally ran the composer command and updated Algolia to version 1.10.0. Now I want to downgrade it back to version 1.8.5. Could you please show me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to revert the `composer.lock` file to the previous version, and then run `composer install`. If you aren't using version control then another option may be to modify your `composer.json` file and set the modules version back to 1.8.5, then run `composer install`.